# get string from ArrayList and convert to usable latitude and longitude

Tags: java, android, google-maps, arraylist

I've been searching for days for an answer to this, but haven't yet had any luck, so I figured I'd just ask.

I have a small local tourism app that I have been working on, and I have the majority of the functionality working, but I can't quite figure out how to pull the latitude and longitude information from each specific item in my ArrayList.

What I have right now, just has the longitude as a double, because the maps app worked correctly if both were hard-coded in, but I want it to work according to the item the user selects.

The Fragment code

```
public class RestaurantsFragment extends Fragment {

private double latitude;
private double longitude;

public RestaurantsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attraction_list, container, false);

    // Create a list of restaurants
    final ArrayList<Attractions> attraction = new ArrayList<Attractions>();
    attraction.add(new Attractions(R.string.black_n_blue, R.string.black_n_blue_contact, R.string.black_n_blue_desc, R.drawable.bnb, R.string.slater_loc));
    attraction.add(new Attractions(R.string.cardona, R.string.cardona_contact, R.string.cardona_desc, R.drawable.cardona, R.string.slater_loc));
    attraction.add(new Attractions(R.string.athos, R.string.athos_contact, R.string.athos_desc, R.drawable.athos, R.string.slater_loc));
    attraction.add(new Attractions(R.string.tanpopo, R.string.tanpopo_contact, R.string.tanpopo_desc, R.drawable.tanpopo, R.string.slater_loc));

    // Create an {@link AttractionsAdapter}, whose data source is a list of {@link Attractions}s. The
    // adapter knows how to create list items for each item in the list.
    AttractionsAdapter adapter = new AttractionsAdapter(getActivity(), attraction, R.color.restaurants);

    // Find the {@link ListView} object in the view hierarchy of the {@link Activity}.
    // There should be a {@link ListView} with the view ID called list, which is declared in the
    // attraction_list.xml layout file.
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Make the {@link ListView} use the {@link AttractionsAdapter} we created above, so that the
    // {@link ListView} will display list items for each {@link Attractions} in the list.
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            // Get the {@link Attractions} object at the given position the user clicked on
            Attractions attractions = attraction.get(position);

            latitude = attractions.getLocation();
            longitude = -73.850338;

            //Open map app to the address
            String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

}
```

And:

```
public class Attractions {
//Image reference source
private int mImageResourceId = NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;
//Attraction name
private int mName;
//Attraction hours
private int mContact;
//Attraction description
private int mDescription;
//Attraction location
private int mLocation;

private static final int NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED = -1;

public Attractions(int name, int contact, int description, int imageResourceId, int location){
    mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    mName = name;
    mContact = contact;
    mDescription = description;
    mLocation = location;
}

public Attractions(int name, int contact, int description, int location){
    mName = name;
    mContact = contact;
    mDescription = description;
    mLocation = location;
}

public boolean hasImage() {
    return mImageResourceId != NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;
}

public int getImageResourceId() {
    return mImageResourceId;
}

public int getName() {
    return mName;
}

public int getContact() {
    return mContact;
}

public int getDescription() {return mDescription;}

public int getLocation() {return mLocation;}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Word{" +
            "mImageResourceId=" + mImageResourceId +
            ", mName='" + mName + '\'' +
            ", mContact='" + mContact + '\'' +
            ", mDescription='" + mDescription + '\'' +
            ", mLocation='" + mLocation + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

And I just have the strings.xml formatted like this:

```
<string name="slater_loc" formatted="false">42.689319</string>
```

Comment: So what is your problem ? You want to convert a string to a double ? Have you tried `double yourLocDouble = Double.parseDouble(yourLocationString)` ?

Comment: I suggest storing the latitude and longitude as doubles in your `Attractions` class. Will your app have a fixed set of restaurants? Or do you want to be able to add more in the future? If the later, you should use a database of some kind to store the restaurant data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Joachim Huet's suggestion, I tried the parseDouble suggestion, which worked exactly as needed.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            // Get the {@link Attractions} object at the given position the user clicked on
            Attractions attractions = attraction.get(position);

            String lat = getString(attractions.getLatitude());
            latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat);
            String lon = getString(attractions.getLongitude());
            longitude = Double.parseDouble(lon);

            //Open map app to the address
            String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This code was added into the Restaurants Fragment. Thank you everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to store/get the coordinates in/from double and String?
In any case, I would try to make two builders. One StringBuilder to build the geo coordinates and a Uri builder to build the Uri and then check if the activity can be resolved, then start.

```
StringBuilder geoString = new StringBuilder();
geoString.append(lat)
    .append(",")
    .append(long);

Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("geo")
    .path(geoString);
Uri addressUri = builder.build();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(addressUri);
if(intent.resolveActivity(getPacketManager()) != null){
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

`